# Toggle prop passed on one of many targets in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just starting off with ReactJS and have a project where I am showing an accordion of issues and including a details area that is hidden on the start.

There is a button in the accordion bar that should pass a prop to the child element to hide or show them. I have refs on the button and on the details child compoment and added a function to call the function and pass the ref of the details area. I am just not sure how to dynamically change the class hidden on one of many areas and not all of them.

Not sure if putting a class on each element and then learning how to toggle the particular child's class is better or changing the prop to the child.

I can get to the change function but am drawing a blank from there and all the googling shows how to do one element with a grand change of state but I need individual elements.

Here is what I have so far.

Parent

```
    ...
      <AccordionItem key={item.id} className={iconClass} title={`${item.area}`} expanded={item === 1}>
  {
    item.issues.map(issue => {
    let trim = (issue.issue.length>21) ? `${issue.issue.substring(0,22)}...`: issue.issue;
 return (
    <div className="issue-bar container-fluid">
      <div className="row issue-bar-row">
          <span className="issue-title"><img src={CriticalRed} alt="Critical"/> {trim}</span>
            <span className="btns">
               <button className="btn btn-details" onClick={() => this.showDetail(`details-${issue.id}`)}>Details</button>
             </span>
       </div>
       <IssuesDetails ref={`details-${issue.id}`} issue={issue} shouldHide={true} />
    </div>
    )
   })
  }
 <div>
</div>
</AccordionItem>
    ...
```

Child

```
export default class IssuesDetails extends Component{

  render(){
    let issueDetails = classNames( 'issue-details', { hidden: this.props.shouldHide } )
    return(
      <div className={issueDetails}>
        <div className="issues-details-title">
          <h3>{this.props.issue.issue}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="issues-details-details">
          {this.props.issue.details}
        </div>
        <div className="issues-details-gallery">
          <ImageGallery source={this.props.issue.photos} showPlayButton={false} useBrowserFullscreen={false} />
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-success">Resolve</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help you provide or places you can send me!

Comment: might be helpful if you can make a running example with minimal code would be far easier to help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

https://codepen.io/JanickFischr/pen/xWEZOG

```
style={{display: this.props.display}}
```

I think it will help with your problem. If you need more information, please just ask.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly, you need to be able to swap out `shouldHide={true}` in certain circumstances. To do this, you'll want your parent component to have a state object which indicates whether they should be hidden or not.

Exactly what this state object looks like depends on what sort of data you're working with. If the issues is a single array, then perhaps the state could be an array of booleans indicating whether each issue is expanded or not. I suspect you may have a more nested data structure, but i can't tell exactly since some of the code was omitted.

So assuming you have an array, it might look like this (i've omitted some things from the render method for brevity):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden: (new Array(props.issues.length)).fill(false),
    };
  }

  showDetail(index) {
    let newHidden = this.state.hidden.slice();
    newHidden[index] = true;
    this.setState({
      hidden: newHidden
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AccordionItem>
        {this.props.issues.map((issue, index) => {
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => this.showDetail(index))}/>
            <IssuesDetails issue={issue} shouldHide={this.state.hidden[index]}/>
          </div>
        })}
      </AccordionItem>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for all the ideas. The only issue is that there are more than one accordion item and each contains the IssueDetails component. So doing a state change would make all the details blocks (one per each accordion item) visible. I need to target just the one. Something like (in jQuery) $('#' + this.id).hide(); so I need to target each child based on the ref. Something like this.ref.props.shouldHide = false (or true)

Comment: Yes, as i mentioned your data structure may need to be more complicated. Is there an array of accordion items, each of which has an array of issues? In that case you may want a 2D array of booleans. Do not use refs to solve this. The whole point of react is to handle the manipulation of the dom for you. You just need to describe to react for a given state and props what you want the dom to look like.

Comment: I think I am understanding what you mean but I am unsure how to create the 2D array after the data is received?

Comment: How are you getting the data, and what format is it in?

Comment: Right now I am getting a large json string that I am using by passing the necessary information as props.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of that data i can't give precise recommendations, but basically in the component's constructor, you'll create a state object with the same shape as the data you get from the props. eg, if props.data is an array of arrays of Issues, the state will be an array of arrays of booleans, each of which is set to false. If the data can change after mounting then you may need to do similar work in componentWillReceiveProps. If this structure is too complex, you may want to break the component into sub components, with each responsible for just one level of the data

Comment: Thank you everyone. Actually I figured it out based on what everyone said and all the examples shown by using one state value. I broken the each list item into a component with the list row and the detail and just used the button from the list to change 1 state which hide or show each detail item. Since each component maintained its own state for the details, it worked like a charm.